# No need to verify us as a human being, twice or more

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, captcha

Do we need it? It's an annoying verification if we must verify us as a human if it's asked more than once.

Please make it only once after the verified process. Further, please delete the weird robotic-human photo on the page.

It's not good for UX (User Experience). Hope this will be changed and fixed.

**UPDATE:** Solved with some explanation.

Comment: What process are you attempting that needs multiple verifications?

Comment: The verification should only get triggered under some conditions - could you edit your question and tell us in more detail what steps you took?

Comment: It's a guard against you using Stack Overflow in the middle of a robotapocalypse. Just because you've proven that you're a human once doesn't mean that a robot hasn't broken into your home, tied you up and has begun editing posts on Stack Overflow from your machine. Stack Overflow must be ever vigilant.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Only reproduce the normal step to post a question. Okay, I just know it. I'm a new member in here, so I need to ask. @Five So that's what should be happen. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Closers, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218344/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252990/282094 - it's SC and NR only if the issue is removed completely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implemented a while ago:

- a 5 minute captcha grace period. So if you solve a captcha once, we don't captcha you again for 5 minutes -- unless you trigger the extreme bot thresholds.
- reduced captcha thresholds for 10k users. Once you get to 10k, you have to go much faster to get the captcha.

Comment: Thanks for your information and the tip!

Comment: has the policy changed yesterday? today (2011-01-22) i posted 4 replays on stackoverflow.com within an hour and for every relpy i had to answer the capcha. the 2 months before there were only 1 capcha per day as maximum

Comment: I just got asked to verify on SO twice in rapid succession. Can't be entirely sure that it was under 5 min, since I like to think before I answer ;)
Anyway, I think there could be an even longer grace period. Why even bother to ask for verification again if it´s the same session and from the same IP?

Answer (score 5):

And remove it please for trusted users.

I'm a member over a year, over 30K reputation. Am I still not trusted enough not to post spam???

Comment: The system trusts *you* not to post spam. It just doesn't necessarily trust *everyone claiming to be you*.

Comment: The probability of account hijacking is very low. Handling manually one such case is a small price to pay for much improved UX for the rest of the users.

Comment: At 10k reputation and above, you do get drastically reduced CAPTCHA timing.

Comment: I'm a member for just 2 days. But I feel that's kinda annoying and unnecessary. @Jon Skeet: Oh. So that's how the system work in here. I just know.